# how to trim and render multiple sequences in premiere

Tags: editing, premiere

I have 30 sequences which are syncronized to start at same time (different cameras of one sport event). Those sequences are couple of hours length.

I need to render some segments of all sequences, lets say  0:10:00 to 0:30:00 and 1:10:00 to 1:30:00. How to do it efficently?

I tried to set time range in media encoder, range settings apply only to one encoding task, not to all selected ones.

The only way known for me is to create 60 more sequences and trim them to length, then export to media encoder and render, but there must be easier way!

Answer (score 1):

I would honestly probably just punch in the range settings for each of the renders separately in Adobe Media Encoder.  It's likely the easiest way to go about it.  It's not that long or hard of a process to punch in start and end times for 30 clips.

The only other remote possibility (I don't think it will work though) would be to see if you can make a preset for the times to be rendered.  You could then apply that preset, but I don't think that information can be stored in a preset. (I don't have Adobe Media Encoder in front of me at the moment.)

Comment: As a programmer at first i've remembered that some of adobe products are scriptable, unfortunately premiere is not one of them, but this thought reminded me about mouse and keyboard automation. I have copied all source sequences two times, than added prefix to their names(one macro run for each prefix), than  set in and out with anouther macro (one run per sequence). Much easier, but still way too many hand work and complications.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to render a lot of clips from one sequence, you can use markers and After Codecs software. It allows to render a lot of clips from one sequence (multirender function).

You can learn more here about this:

https://www.autokroma.com/blog/Batch-Export-Clips-Quickly-Premiere-Pro-with-our-Panel/

In case if you need to render parts like 0:10:00 to 0:30:00 and 1:10:00 to 1:30:00.

And you need to render these two parts for example for video track 1, video track 2, 3, 4 etc... Then I think you can create the script with AutoHotKey or similar software, that will make subclip or subsequence with needed tracks for you. It can be done using only keyboard.
Maybe ExtendScript will work too in this case, but it need to test.